# AWS Lambda Dynamo AWS SDK Node.js Query Method Issue

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Hello I have the following Lambda code based on Node.js. I am unable to call the query method to retrieve the data.

Input: `{ key: 'value' }` -- Using Test Event Input.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'Chapter',
        IndexName: 'subjectId-index', // Global Secondary Index
        KeyConditionExpression: 'subjectId = :subjectId',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':subjectId': event.key,
        },
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
    ddb.query(params, (err, data) => {
        // Console.log('Not executing this part !!!')
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

The query method not even being called or any error being logged. I really could use some help.

Comment: which version of nodejs are you using in the Lambda config?

Answer (score -1):

As you have console logs, you can debug your code using cloudwatch to check your lambda logs.

You can select your lambda and if you are seeing any execution logs you can click for more details and you will find your console logs there

Call context.done

Sample program you might try. I just wrote it not tried

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-2' });
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

const executeQuery = (params) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ddb.query(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'Chapter',
        IndexName: 'subjectId-index', // Global Secondary Index
        KeyConditionExpression: 'subjectId = :subjectId',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':subjectId': event.key,
        },
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
    executeQuery(params).then((data) => {
        console.log('sucess');
        context.done(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error occurred');
        context.done(error);
    })
};
```

Comment: It is not about cloudWatch Logs. That is working I am able to see the logs there when I set it as trigger for a dynamo db table. But my query function is not being called.

Comment: You are not using callback contex.done after completing your task. Please read my answer for codebase

Comment: Using promise is not required. Event the document doesn't require so. All I need to know why my query() method of dynamo client object is not executing.

Comment: lambda function requires to call contex.done for wait till execution
else lambda will exit on timeout & default time is 3s for lambda

If you don't want to execute it with promise try to increase timeout of lambda you should be able to see the logs

Comment: Currently testing it in the aws online editor with node.js v8.x.x

Comment: I am asking you to increase lambda execution time from aws console.
Refer this image https://files.readme.io/13d03c1-jiralambda-advanced.png